# undefined reference to function after changing function declaration

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I have a file bridge.h, which contains a function declaration:

```
int getDisplayPt();
```

I also have a .cpp file which calls this function:

```
int b = getDisplayPt();
```

It all builds and links beautifully.

Now I need to change the function. The new declaration is:

```
int getDisplayPt(bool*);
```

And in the .cpp file:

```
bool result;
int b = getDisplayPt(&result);
```

Now I'm getting an error "undefined reference to `getDisplayPt(bool*)'"

I thought that maybe the files are not linked correctly and the function makes a call to some other class. So I changed my .cpp file back:

```
int b = getDisplayPt();
```

And now I got this:

error: too few arguments to function 'int getDisplayPt(bool*)'

So I believe that the .cpp is indeed calling the function I thought it was calling. But why won't my code link??

Thanks...

Comment: Did you also change the definition of `getDisplayPt`? That's the place in .cpp where its body is.

Answer (score 2):

You have changed the header and the calling code. You will also need to change the definition of the `getDisplayPt` function.

Comment: Oh right, I see what you mean. Yes, that must be the case. Trying to find the definition now...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you either never defined `getDisplayPt()` or didn't update the file where you defined it.

Comment: Well that is what I thought, but when I change the code in the .cpp file back, the error changes to "error: too few arguments to function 'int getDisplayPt(bool*)'", so I believe it means that my code calls the right (updated) function...

Comment: I'm not talking about the file that calls the function, I'm talking about the file that defines it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4d5ssht.aspx